# ImageBackground not showing image on some devices

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use a CustomCallout with a ImageBackground in it. I notice a really strange behavior when testing the application on two different devices (both Android). The image is showed correctly on the older device with lower display, but on the new device (p30 lite) the image is not appearing.. any ideas? here is my code:

```
class CustomCallout extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);        
      }


  render() {
    return (

      <View style={styles.calloutStyle}>
        <View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.placeRow, ...styles.placeHeader }}>

            <ImageBackground
              source={{ uri: this.props.image }}
              style={styles.bgImage}
            >
              <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={1}>
                  {this.props.placeName}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </ImageBackground>

          </View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.placeRow, ...styles.placeDetail }}>
            <Text>{this.props.distance}m</Text>
            <Text>{this.getPlaceType(this.props.placeType)}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.placeRow, ...styles.placeRating }}>
              <StarRating
                disabled={false}
                emptyStar={'ios-star-outline'}
                fullStar={'ios-star'}
                halfStar={'ios-star-half'}
                iconSet={'Ionicons'}
                maxStars={7}
                rating={4}                
                fullStarColor={'#FDCC0D'}
                starSize={20}
              />
          </View>
        </View>                 
      </View>

    );
  }
}

CustomCallout.propTypes = propTypes;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  calloutStyle: {
    height: 200,
    width: 280,
    backgroundColor: '#61adc8',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2},
    shadowRadius: 6,
    shadowOpacity: 0.26,
    elevation: 55,
    padding: 12,
    borderRadius: 20,
    shadowColor: 'black',
    overflow: 'hidden'
  },
   bgImage: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  placeRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  placeHeader: {
    height: '80%'
  },
  placeDetail: {
    justifyContent: 'space-between',    
    height: '10%'
  },
  placeRating: {   
    height: '10%',
    justifyContent:'flex-start',
  },
  titleContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2},
    shadowRadius: 6,
    shadowOpacity: 0.26,
    elevation: 55,    
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  title: {        
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20
  }
});

export default CustomCallout;
```

Comment: try to give flex:1 on the bgImage styles

Comment: still not working..

Answer (score 0):

We cant put ImageBackground wherever we want.. I don't know the exact theory. But Just put the ImageBackgroung tag outside the view and try to even put on different views too.. If anyone know plz correct me. Here is a working example.

Put ImageBackground to entire component

```
render() {
    return (

      <View style={styles.calloutStyle}>
        <View>

            <ImageBackground
              source={{ uri: 'https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg' }}
              style={styles.bgImage}
            >
          <View style={{ ...styles.placeRow, ...styles.placeHeader }}>

              <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={1}>
                  {this.props.placeName}
                </Text>
              </View>

          </View>

            </ImageBackground>
          <View style={{ ...styles.placeRow, ...styles.placeDetail }}>
            <Text>{this.props.distance}m</Text>
            <Text>{this.getPlaceType(this.props.placeType)}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.placeRow, ...styles.placeRating }}>
              <StarRating
                disabled={false}
                emptyStar={'ios-star-outline'}
                fullStar={'ios-star'}
                halfStar={'ios-star-half'}
                iconSet={'Ionicons'}
                maxStars={7}
                rating={4}                
                fullStarColor={'#FDCC0D'}
                starSize={20}
              />
          </View>

        </View>                 
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

Or you can put to only both components

```
render() {
    return (

      <View style={styles.calloutStyle}>
        <View>

            <ImageBackground
              source={{ uri: 'https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg' }}
              style={styles.bgImage}
            >
          <View style={{ ...styles.placeRow, ...styles.placeHeader }}>

              <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={1}>
                  {this.props.placeName}
                </Text>
              </View>

          </View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.placeRow, ...styles.placeDetail }}>
            <Text>{this.props.distance}m</Text>
            <Text>{this.getPlaceType(this.props.placeType)}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.placeRow, ...styles.placeRating }}>
              <StarRating
                disabled={false}
                emptyStar={'ios-star-outline'}
                fullStar={'ios-star'}
                halfStar={'ios-star-half'}
                iconSet={'Ionicons'}
                maxStars={7}
                rating={4}                
                fullStarColor={'#FDCC0D'}
                starSize={20}
              />
          </View>

            </ImageBackground>
        </View>                 
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

or put ImageBackground to inside view only

```
render() {
    return (

      <View style={styles.calloutStyle}>
        <View>

            <ImageBackground
              source={{ uri: 'https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg' }}
              style={styles.bgImage}
            >
          <View style={{ ...styles.placeRow, ...styles.placeHeader }}>

              <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={1}>
                  {this.props.placeName}
                </Text>
              </View>

          </View>

            </ImageBackground>
          <View style={{ ...styles.placeRow, ...styles.placeDetail }}>
            <Text>{this.props.distance}m</Text>
            <Text>{this.getPlaceType(this.props.placeType)}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.placeRow, ...styles.placeRating }}>
              <StarRating
                disabled={false}
                emptyStar={'ios-star-outline'}
                fullStar={'ios-star'}
                halfStar={'ios-star-half'}
                iconSet={'Ionicons'}
                maxStars={7}
                rating={4}                
                fullStarColor={'#FDCC0D'}
                starSize={20}
              />
          </View>

        </View>                 
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

Try this out and let me know the result.. :)

Comment: none of the proposed solutions helped.. they changed the styling but the image is still not appearing on the second device.

Comment: have you passed the image from props or the url ive given.. Sorry because it is working on my device so I asked

Comment: yes, I also tried with local image. Its displaying on the older phone, but not on the new one.. really strange behavior